# Integrating CKEDITOR.replace and Perch to use two editors

Tags: ckeditor, perch

In CKEDITOR's documentation there are suggestions to use the following in the config.js file:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    config.toolbar_Full = [
         { name: 'document', items : [ 'Source','-',
           'Save','NewPage','DocProps','Preview',
           'Print','-','Templates' ] }
    ];
    config.toolbar = 'Full';
 };
```

Though that actually does not work.  It only works without the parens:

```
 CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    config.toolbar_Full = [
         [ 'Source','-','Save','NewPage','DocProps',
           'Preview','Print','-','Templates' ]
    ];
    config.toolbar = 'Full';
 };
```

Now, Perch also has this little rig: CKEDITOR.replace that is meant to be used inline, but I would like to use it in the config.js file.  How do I rewrite the call to CKEDITOR.replace so that it works inside config.js?

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    toolbar : 'Full'
});

CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor2', {
    toolbar : 'Basic'
});
```

Comment: Actually, the code in your first example does work. You should probably try to get a basic set up working before you try to change things. Have you checked if the files located in the ckeditor/_samples folder load correctly?  The ckeditor/INSTALL.html file recommends that you verify your installation is working correctly by looking at the sample files. The samples files have examples of how to modify the toolbar settings.

Answer (score 1):

As I replied in [CKEditor forums](http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?p=59969#p59969), you must be using an old version of CKEditor, that toolbar syntax was introduced in CKEditor 3.6

Answer (score 0):

Just load the CKEditor with your custom config:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
  toolbar: [ 'Source','-','Save','NewPage','DocProps','Preview','Print','-','Templates' ]
});
```

Or define your custom toolbar and load it:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor2', {
  toolbar_Custom: [ 'Source','-','Save','NewPage','DocProps','Preview','Print','-','Templates' ],
  toolbar: 'Custom'
});
```